# mysql selecting multiple values wrapped in identical tags

Tags: mysql

I don't know if there is a better description of my problem, but here is what I need help with:

I have a field with lots of data, and the part I need to solve looks like this:

```
::field_x::<br />||field_x||519||/field_x||<br />||field_x||281||/field_x||<br />::/field_x::
```

I have to extract each number (id) from this, 519 and 281 in this example, and insert them in a field in another table, separated by spaces or commas. I know how to use SUBSTRING - LOCATE method, but that would return only the first instance, so is there a method to extract them all in one go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SUBSTRING INDEX LOCATE` will work. There is no built in functionality for regular expressions so unless you handle it before it gets to mysql...you're stuck using the `SUBSTRING INDEX LOCATE` method...

If you need to iterate through a dataset, you will need to initiate a cursor, or `FOR` loop and use a stored proc.

[parse results in MySQL via REGEX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412895/parse-results-in-mysql-via-regex)