# Find matching substrings within table row using regex

Tags: mysql

I have two table columns, one with an id and the other with the webpage content storing href links. I would like to write an SQL query using regex that finds all href links within the table row and strips all other characters. Currently stuck with the code below.

```sql
SELECT id,web_data FROM web_data_table WHERE web_data REGEXP 'href'
```

Current output:

```
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| id |                            web_data                            |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | random txt,href="link1"                                        |
|  2 | random txt, random txt, href="link2", href="link3", random txt |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Desired output:

```
+----+---------------------------+
| id |         web_data          |
+----+---------------------------+
|  1 | href="link1"              |
|  2 | href="link2" href="link3" |
+----+---------------------------+
```

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Currently using 8.0

Comment: this might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412895/parse-results-in-mysql-via-regex

Comment: I think you will have to select and retrieve rows with complete `web_data` columns where there is at least one link and then use the regex engine of your programming language to find all links in each row.